# How to copy wide string in VC++ 2003

Tags: visual-c++, wchar-t

Hi could you please help us in copying one wchar_t* to another wchar_t*.

I'm using the following code:

```
wchar_t* str1=L"sreeni";
wchar_t* str2; 

wcscpy(str2,str1);
```

In the last line I'm getting a run time error as without allocating memory to *str2, i'm trying to copy the value of str1;

is there any method like wcscpy to copy wchar_t pointer to another wchar_t pointer?

I dont want to use wide character arrays, i.e there shouldn't be any restriction on the size of string. And I want to copy the content of complete string str1 into string str2.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean you want to duplicate the string, rather than just the pointer.

wcsdup() is the wide equivalent of strdup(), which will allocate the memory for the duplicated string.